# создать массив из многомерного массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть многомерный массив вида:

```
[
    0 => [
        0 => '71'
        1 => [
            0 => [
                0 => 'time'
                1 => 1522957532
            ]
            1 => [
                0 => 'user_id'
                1 => '111'
            ]
            2 => [
                0 => 'status'
                1 => 2
            ]
        ]
    ]
    1 => [
        0 => '57'..
```

Подскажите как привести в такой вид:

```
[ 0 => [
   'id' => '71', 
   'time' => 1522957532,
   'user_id' => '111',
   'status' => 2
]..
```

Comment: foreach($arr as $item){
  echo 'id= '.$item[0][0].'<br>';
  echo $item[1][0][0].'='.$item[1][0][1].'<br>';
  echo $item[1][1][0].'='.$item[1][1][1].'<br>';
  echo $item[1][2][0].'='.$item[1][2][1].'<br>';
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функциями `array_map` и `array_column`

```
$result = array_map(function($v){
                return [ 'id' => $v[0] ] + array_column($v[1], 1, 0);
            }, $data);
```